# Unit Testing the sender object in EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

Lets say I have a eventhandler like so:

```
public SomethingHappended_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var myobj = sender as MyClass();
  myobj.DoSomethingImportant();
}
```

How can I test that myObj is the type of MyClass? I know that the sender will always be of MyClass but I just thought to be safe I would need a:

```
if (myObj != null) //Close it
```

If the type is not MyClass then myObj will be null. As I know its best to test for the not null how can I create a unit test to prove that if I send a different type as the sender other than MyClass it will fall over calling DoSomethingImportant and therefore I need the null check?

Comment: whats wrong with the standard type check if (myobj == null)...

Comment: @Lloyd You still need to cast the sender to be able to call the methods on it

Comment: You're basically asking for a test to see whether 'as' does what it is supposed to do - IMHO you shouldn't need to "unit test" at the level of whether C# works the way it's documented.  'as' will simply not cast unless the object you're trying to cast is of that class or a subtype of that class.  If you really want to, though, simply write another chunk of code that safely casts using 'as', or test for type directly using the 'is' keyword.  Or, the event handler is just a method in a class, write a test for it as you would any class.

Comment: I'm not asking how to test 'as' I want to test that if some other type comes in that my code doesn't fall over

Comment: Or just cast it - `(MyClass)sender`. You'll get an InvalidCastException if it fails. Since you know that the sender will always be of type MyClass, then this is definitely an error condition.

Comment: @TrueWill but you're not proving anything in your tests to show you've accounted for it

Comment: @Jon - While I'm a believer in TDD, I'm not a purist. I'd call this more of a precondition, and I'm depending on C# casting to verify that. Code Contracts might be a better choice than unit tests for cases like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can answer you in pseudo-code to point out what you could do.

First off you can check if sender is of type MyClass.

```
if(sender is MyClass)
```

Then in your unittest you can send in two mock objects, one of type MyClass and one of another type "MyClassFake". Make an interface both use and make them implement the Close() method.

Make two unittests:

1. Validate that MyClass.Close() is called.
2. Validate that MyClassFake.Close() is never called.

Close() is just an example, if you have other methods, you can test called/not called against them.